# R: How to calculate values of 1,5*IQR whiskers

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

How can I calculate the values of the top and bottom border of 1,5×IQR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `boxplot.stats()` function used by `boxplot()`:

```
R> boxplot.stats(rnorm(100))
$stats
[1] -2.3865817 -0.7195878  0.0889332  0.6237745  2.3702410

$n
[1] 100

$conf
[1] -0.123318  0.301184

$out
numeric(0)

R>
```

It is documented to give this:

> Value:
>
> ```
>  List with named components as follows:
> ```
>
> stats: a vector of length 5, containing the extreme of the lower
>             whisker, the lower ‘hinge’, the median, the upper ‘hinge’ and
>             the extreme of the upper whisker.
>
> ```
>    n: the number of non-‘NA’ observations in the sample.
>
> conf: the lower and upper extremes of the ‘notch’ (‘if(do.conf)’).
>       See the details.
>
>  out: the values of any data points which lie beyond the extremes
>       of the whiskers (‘if(do.out)’).
>  Note that ‘$stats’ and ‘$conf’ are sorted in _in_creasing order,
>  unlike S, and that ‘$n’ and ‘$out’ include any ‘+- Inf’ values.
> ```